# Macvtap Bridge to VM Host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I'm trying to get a solid web/media server going in my home. It's a repurposed i7-920 machine.
Its running Kubuntu 15.10, KVM, and a Windows 7 Pro vm (VT-x, Spice, QXL, MacVTap)

I have Windows 7 trimmed down to almost just Windows Media center, this is my PVR. I want it to map network drives to ~/DVR and ~/Plex/* on Kubuntu.

So I install virt-manager, spin up the VM, put it on a virtual network that uses macvtap to bridge my ethernet to Windows.
I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I used to see Network Manager pick up on a duplicate Ethernet with (macvtap) in the name. My guest now however, can't see the host, which brought me to this [article](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Guest_can_reach_outside_network,_but_can't_reach_host_(macvtap))

And these [directions](http://www.furorteutonicus.eu/2013/08/04/enabling-host-guest-networking-with-kvm-macvlan-and-macvtap/)

However in the directions, they have a script and a broken link to the command references.

Now Kubuntu is in a weird state, which doesn't help my confusion. It has Network-Manager, and bridge-utils. However bridge-utils aren't used, instead 'ip' is used and it's own set of file paths as etc/network/interfaces is empty.

To minimize confusion I built my bridge in virt-manager, because the whole systemd jump cut down on docs.

Can someone point me to the right config, and syntax to use to make my host OS a client of the hypervisor's macvtap bridge?

This is prerequisite to me playing with snapraid and drive pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to kill the [extra networks](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking#Basic_command_line_usage_for_virtual_networks) using:

```
net-destroy [network name]
```

libvirt was responsible for the extra unused bridges, not Network-Manager (the gui ip utility) or bridge-utils.

I got a wonderful explanation of how this works on irc a week or two ago, where a user kindly recommended that I create an NAT Network between the Kubuntu Host and the Windows VM. This runs simultaneously with the macvtap connection.

On windows I now have two ip addresses on two nics. 192.168.x.124 for my physical network. And 192.168.y.100 for the virtual network.

In CMD, I used the command

```
nbtstat -a RemoteName
```

This gave me the ip address of the host (192.168.y.280) on the virtual network. I used this address to mount my Samba Share (/mnt/wdg/media/) as a network drive Z:\media\

Now I can record tv shows on Windows Media Center, and have them copied directly to my 'Recorded TV' library in Plex, which is at the /mnt/wdg/media/PVR directory.